# embed JS code in a batch file

Tags: javascript, batch-file

i have a batch file preparing word files by renaming and relocating them. 
so that i make pdf for this files using a javascript code i ve found in this website. i call it as follows;

```
for %%g in ("test\*.doc") do (cscript.exe //nologo "SAVEASPDF.js" "%%~fg")
```

this JavaScript code is in another file as `saveaspdf.js` to make PDF.
can i embed a JS code inside the batch file (e.g. as a `:FUNCTION`)  to keep all the code in a single file only?

here is the JS i m trying to embed, i found it here in this website.

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var docPath = WScript.Arguments(0);
docPath = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(docPath);

var pdfPath = docPath.replace(/\.doc[^.]*$/, ".pdf");
var objWord = null;

try
{
    WScript.Echo("Saving '" + docPath + "' as '" + pdfPath + "'...");

    objWord = new ActiveXObject("Word.Application");
    objWord.Visible = false;

    var objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(docPath);

    var wdFormatPdf = 17;
    objDoc.SaveAs(pdfPath, wdFormatPdf);
    objDoc.Close();

    WScript.Echo("Done.");
}
finally
{
    if (objWord != null)
    {
        objWord.Quit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many methods posted for embedding and executing JScript within a batch script. Here are a few:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15169687/1012053
   This is my favorite, and the one I will use below
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4999378/1012053
   I don't like this method because it defines an extra (unwanted) environment variable.
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15176096/1012053 (before the EDIT)
   Another excellent choice.
4. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9074483/1012053 (The final UPDATE 2014-04-27 at the bottom)
   This WSF technique is not quite as convenient, but it is powerful in that you can embed and execute any number of independent JScript and/or VBS jobs within a single batch script.

So here is how you could use option 1. to combine the two scripts into a single file:

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* Harmless hybrid line that begins a JScript comment

:: ******* Begin batch code *********
@echo off
for %%g in ("test\*.doc") do cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" "%%~fg"
exit /b

********* Begin JScript code **********/
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var docPath = WScript.Arguments(0);
docPath = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(docPath);

var pdfPath = docPath.replace(/\.doc[^.]*$/, ".pdf");
var objWord = null;

try
{
    WScript.Echo("Saving '" + docPath + "' as '" + pdfPath + "'...");

    objWord = new ActiveXObject("Word.Application");
    objWord.Visible = false;

    var objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(docPath);

    var wdFormatPdf = 17;
    objDoc.SaveAs(pdfPath, wdFormatPdf);
    objDoc.Close();

    WScript.Echo("Done.");
}
finally
{
    if (objWord != null)
    {
        objWord.Quit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ECHO 'YOUR_JS_CODE' | node
```

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php

Comment: If his javascript code is only one line long _and_ he has node.js installed, sure. But there are way better ways to do that.

Comment: For multiple lines they could use this trick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294599/do-batch-files-support-multiline-variables , and given that they are talking about making a PDF using a local `.exe` from JS code, it's safe to assume they have node.js installed.  Also if you know of a better way why not create an answer explaining it?

Comment: Ok, FYI I don't think that kind of comment on a working solution is helpful at all. OP wanted a solution and I gave him one quick. If your fear is that a weak answer gets accepted and recorded for posterity then you can always post an answer later, I will gladly remove mine if yours is genuinely better.

Comment: Well my argument was that your solution might not be reasonable, depending on how long OP's code is. Until saveaspdf.js is posted, it's impossible to say.

Comment: thanks, it is not one line, i added the saveaspdf.js

Answer (score -1):

If you look at the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff920171.aspx) for `cscript.exe` it seems that it wants to read the script from a file so I believe you are out of luck here.

Running it via nodejs as lleaff suggested might have worked if your script was compatible with nodejs but since you are using [ActiveXObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sw4ddf8(v=vs.94).aspx) to automate Word it wouldn't execute.

Comment: Well, the batch script is a file, so CSCRIPT can read the JScript code embedded within the batch script. It isn't very difficult. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34512715/1012053)