# Batch script - /* and */ what does it do?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have here a sample code that I use (came from another stackoverflow thread). I don't have any question on how this runs.

**I am just wondering what are the `/*` and `*/` symbols for?**

```
    @set @a=0  /*

    ::modify input file and output file
    @cscript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" < names.txt > output.txt

    ::modify output file and result file
    :: @move /Y output.txt names_result.csv
    type output.txt > names_result.csv

    ::end
    @goto :EOF */


WScript.Stdout.Write(WScript.StdIn.ReadAll().replace(/\t/g,","));
```

Comment: This is kind of an indirect answer, found in this stackoverflow thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29815636/and-in-java-comments/29815698 Short-hand /* */ is used to write block (multi line) comments in javascript

Comment: hi steven, yes i know this is comment on java. But this is batch scripting that I am on right now. Comments for batch is "REM" and "::". But not "/*" and */".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a way to embed a java script in a cmd file. [See also here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325420/embed-javascript-in-bat-files)
The trick is to make JS believe it's defining `set`, and after that the `/*` `*/` will gobble the cmd lines that have been used to run the script. Just read it two times, once as a cmd shell and once as the JS engine.

Comment: awesome! that explains it well. Thank you very much yacc!